# Cv2 frame number of video gives different results

Tags: object-detection, opencv, avi, python

I try to detect objects on video. The video format is AVI. I check the frame number of the video with this code:

```
import cv2 
  
data = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/video.avi")  
frames = data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
print("Frame Number:", frames )
```

Frame number is calculated as **90022**. Then I run this code:

```
import cv2 
vid = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/video.avi")

count = 0
ret, frame = vid.read()
while ret:
    count += 1

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    ret, frame = vid.read()

print(count)
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The count is calculated as **18005**. Why the result is different from each other? I want to calculate the exact time of the detection. I need to know in what seconds of the video the detected objects are. I cannot do it because the number of frames is different.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with second `ret, frame = vid.read()`. Try this, it worked for me:

Approach #1:

```
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4") # .avi
count = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    count += 1

print(count)
video.release()
```

Approach #2:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4") # .avi
length = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print(length)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Both give the same value when applied with Mp4. But when the video format is avi, I am having the problem I mentioned above. My video is long. I don't want to convert from avi to mp4.

Comment: It's working for both formats on my computer.

Comment: I tried your code. It is working. Approach 1 and approach 2 give the same results for mp4 but Approach 1 and approach 2 do not give the same results for avi. I think you don't understand my problem. Two formats should give the same answer for avi but it does not. I try to fix that

Comment: it's strange. I have tried it for both formats and everything is correct. I don't know why it's not working for you- [image](https://imgur.com/a/riUpn7j)

Comment: The video has smi and avi file. I can reach the file from avi. I think the format is different from other avi. Because I try another avi video. Two approaches gives the same result.